# Should the window.statechange be triggered when I navigate back from an external link?

Tags: html, history.js

I'm using History.js (the jquery.history.js v1.8b2). Chrome version 30.0.1599.101 m.

I can't figure out how to make History.js work the way I'd expect.

I have a page that has two links. The first simulates an ajax operation. It just changes the text in an `<h2>` in the page from "start" to "2". The second link just points to google.com.

Here's what I do:

- Clear cache in chrome
- Load the page
- Click the first link (I call pushState, statechange occurs and there I update my text to "2")
- Click the google.com link (goes to google)
- Click the browser Back button.

Upon back button click, I expect that the statechange handler should be called and I would then get my state object so I could restore the text to "2".

But the handler is not called. So my page is left with text "start" (the cached page in the browser). Interestingly, the url is set to the "2" version that I pushed in my pushState call.

Am I missing something? Here is my code:

```
<h2 id="state">start</h2>

<a id="2" class="button" href="#">Goto State 2</a>

<a href="http://google.com">Goto google</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        History.Adapter.bind(window, "statechange", function() {
            console.log("statechange called");

            var state = History.getState();

            if (state.data.mystate) {
                // Restore the old state
                $("#state").text(state.data.mystate);
            } else {
                // Start state
                $("#state").text("start");
            }
        });


        $(".button").click(function(e) {
            // push the state we're transitioning to
            var newState = $(this).attr("id");

            History.pushState(
                { mystate: newState },
                "at state " + newState,
                "http://localhost:50494/PushState?state=" + newState);

            // statechange will be called now, and we'll update the page from our newState

            e.preventDefault();
        });


    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no, the statechange isn't supposed to be called when navigating back from outside the page.

I noticed that the demo at http://browserstate.github.com/history.js/demo/ was working as I'd expect, so I did a view source to see how it was working. From what I can tell, here is how you are supposed to use History.js.

1. When your page loads, you look at History.getState().data. **If you recognize one of your states there**, then it means you are navigating back into your page from a different page, like from an external link you went to. (Note: the browser may have just loaded your page from cache or it could have been reloaded from the server. Shouldn't matter because you're going to update the page/ui with the state you just found). So, update your page to that state. **If you didn't recognize the state**, then it's a first time load as far as your page is concerned. Init appropriately.
2. The statechange event will get called upon the browser back/forward button between "ajax" states within your page (states you've pushed while in this one page). **It will also get called when you call pushState()**. Huh, isn't that confusing? Yes, so when you want to transition to a new state within your page, follow this pattern:
3. Prepare your state object (could involve an ajax call),
4. Call `pushState(yourObject,...)`
5. Don't update your page/ui yet.
6. You actually update your page/ui from the statechanged handler that's gonna get called in a moment.

I mistakenly thought you were supposed to do all the work of updating the page, then push the state afterward. This will just make things hard, since statechanged is gonna get called too.

Also, it appears that in general, you should push states for ajax-like transitions within the one page you're on. Don't push states for links you follow outside the page (unless you really understand all this and are trying to do something fancy).

I've updated the sample code here to show what's working for me now:

```
<h2 id="state">start</h2>

<a id="2" class="button" href="#">Goto State 2</a>

<a href="http://google.com">Goto google</a>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        // page loading, check for available state I recognize
        var availableState = History.getState();

        if (!availableState.data.mystate) {
            // loading for the first time
            $("#state").text("start");
        } else {
            // load from the available state
            loadState(availableState);
        }

        History.Adapter.bind(window, "statechange", function () {
            var state = History.getState();
            loadState(state);
        });

        function loadState(state) {
            if (state.data.mystate) {
                // update the page to this state
                $("#state").text(state.data.mystate);
            } else {
                // update the page to the initial state
                $("#state").text("start");
            }
        }


        $(".button").click(function (e) {
            // The user clicked a button, so we want to transition to a new state
            // in this page. Push the state we're transitioning to (which we've hidden
            // in the id attribute in this example).
            var newState = $(this).attr("id");

            History.pushState(
                { mystate: newState },
                "at state " + newState, // title
                "?state=" + newState);  // url

            // statechange will be called now, and we'll update the page from our newState

            e.preventDefault();
        });


    });

</script>
```